# Make image rotate in table while hovering the row

Tags: html, css

I have made the image rotate on hover but the mouse has to be over the image.
How do I make the image rotate when the row is on hover?
I've tryed adding the table in the css where the hover is but I am probably doing it wrong.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Contest</th>
              <th>Fee</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>1&nbsp;<img class="aa" src="img/a.png"></th>
              <th>2&nbsp;<img class="aa" src="img/b.png"></th>
              <th>3&nbsp;<img class="aa" src="img/c.png"></th>
              <th>4&nbsp;<img class="aa" src="img/d.png"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="myTable">
            <tr>
              <td><img class="rotate" src="img/other/rotate.png">&nbsp;A</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>C</td>
              <td>D</td>
              <td>E</td>
              <td>F</td>
              <td><div class="btn btn-success btn-sm">GGG</div></td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

And the CSS:

```
.rotate {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.rotate:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: just add style to `tr:hover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change the CSS selector to rotate an object of class `.rotate` within a `tr:hover` like this:

```
.rotate {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

tr:hover .rotate{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

see also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6rjvxgz/).